# ISNULL from Mysql not showing Results on webpage via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I'm working on a server based POS and I have a php page that displays the client current money on a table, I have 2 tables (Mov_ctes and Clientes), it works fine when I add WITH ROLLUP on the mysql query, It displays the Total but without A Name (NULL value), so I used

```
IFNULL(Clientes.Nombre,'TOTAL')
```

so It could change the NULL value to TOTAL, I entered the whole command on mysql and worked fine, however if I enter the same query via PHP it doesnt output the "Nombre" column

heres my code and a Mysql screenshot

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("source/style.css");
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$log=$_SESSION['sesion'];
$nombr=$_SESSION['username'];
if($log==1)
{
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pw","My_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//Mysql query 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Clientes.cliente_id,IFNULL(Clientes.Nombre,'TOTAL'), sum(Mov_ctes.Movimiento) FROM Clientes NATURAL LEFT JOIN Mov_ctes GROUP BY Nombre WITH ROLLUP");
echo "<table id='hor-minimalist-b' summary='Employee Pay Sheet'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th scope='col'>ID</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>Nombre</th>";
echo "<th scope='col'>Saldo</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cliente_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Nombre'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sum(Mov_ctes.Movimiento)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

[image: Mysql screenshot]

Comment: To be honest, you ought to handle `NULL -> 'Total'`  in the presentation layer, not the database layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an alias for the column, otherwise the column name will be `IFNULL(Clientes.Nombre,'TOTAL')`:

```
SELECT IFNULL(Clientes.Nombre,'TOTAL') AS Nombre
...
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now, didnt notice that, tx alot Marcus Adams :)